# Android: How do i track location from emulator?

Tags: android

I have followed this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_location_based_services.htm) to do a GPS tracker application. When i press the button get location then the application has stopped. I checked in LogCat and error has shown at displayCurrentLocation(). Can i track the location when i run the application from emulator? I can see the manual setup for location control in DDMS. Will it be useful to track the location from emulator?

Here is my activity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{
LocationClient mLocationClient;
private TextView addressLabel;
private TextView locationLabel;
private Button getLocationBtn;
private Button disconnectBtn;
private Button connectBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  locationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationLabel);
  addressLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressLabel);
  getLocationBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getLocation);

  getLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
        displayCurrentLocation();
     }
  });
  disconnectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect);  
  disconnectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        locationLabel.setText("Got disconnected....");
     }
  });
  connectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);  
  connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
        mLocationClient.connect();
        locationLabel.setText("Got connected....");
     }
  });   
  // Create the LocationRequest object
  mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);   
}   
@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  // Connect the client.
  mLocationClient.connect();
  locationLabel.setText("Got connected....");
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
  // Disconnect the client.
  mLocationClient.disconnect();
  super.onStop();
  locationLabel.setText("Got disconnected....");
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
  // Display the connection status
  Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
  // Display the connection status
  Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
  // Display the error code on failure
  Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Failure : " + 
  connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void displayCurrentLocation() {
  // Get the current location's latitude & longitude
  Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
  String msg = "Current Location: " +
  Double.toString(currentLocation.getLatitude()) + "," +
  Double.toString(currentLocation.getLongitude());

  // Display the current location in the UI
  locationLabel.setText(msg);

  // To display the current address in the UI
  (new GetAddressTask(this)).execute(currentLocation);
}
/*
* Following is a subclass of AsyncTask which has been used to get
* address corresponding to the given latitude & longitude.
*/
private class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, String>{
  Context mContext;
  public GetAddressTask(Context context) {
     super();
     mContext = context;
  }

  /*
   * When the task finishes, onPostExecute() displays the address. 
   */
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String address) {
     // Display the current address in the UI
     addressLabel.setText(address);
  }
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Location... params) {
     Geocoder geocoder =
     new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
     // Get the current location from the input parameter list
     Location loc = params[0];
     // Create a list to contain the result address
     List<Address> addresses = null;
     try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
        loc.getLongitude(), 1);
     } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e("LocationSampleActivity", 
        "IO Exception in getFromLocation()");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return ("IO Exception trying to get address");
     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
        // Error message to post in the log
        String errorString = "Illegal arguments " +
        Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()) +
        " , " +
        Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()) +
        " passed to address service";
        Log.e("LocationSampleActivity", errorString);
        e2.printStackTrace();
        return errorString;
     }
     // If the reverse geocode returned an address
     if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        // Get the first address
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        /*
        * Format the first line of address (if available),
        * city, and country name.
        */
        String addressText = String.format(
        "%s, %s, %s",
        // If there's a street address, add it
        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ?
        address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
        // Locality is usually a city
        address.getLocality(),
        // The country of the address
        address.getCountryName());
        // Return the text
        return addressText;
     } else {
        return "No address found";
     }
  }
 }
```

xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button android:id="@+id/getLocation"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/get_location"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/disconnect"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/disconnect"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/connect"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/connect"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/locationLabel"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/addressLabel"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please guide me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
 07-26 05:02:38.399: D/AndroidRuntime(3408): Shutting down VM 
 07-26 05:02:38.399: W/dalvikvm(3408): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught      exception (group=0xb2d1eb20)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408): Process: com.example.gpstracker, PID: 3408
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408): java.lang.NullPointerException
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at       com.example.gpstracker.MainActivity.displayCurrentLocation(MainActivity.java:103)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at   com.example.gpstracker.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 07-26 05:02:38.399: E/AndroidRuntime(3408):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Don't just tell us there was a crash, post the stack trace so we can see what it is.  Most likely its lastLocation returning null because it doesn't have a last location.

Comment: Yes I have edited with stack trace.

Comment: Its what I thought-  it doesn't have a location ready, and you call getLastLocation so it returns null.  You can't assume it always knows a location.  If you absolutely need a location, request location updates.  GetLastLocation shouldn't be relied on

Answer (score 0):

yes you can track longitude and latitude in emulator, you must set location value in DDMS Emulator Control, its good for testing but Based on my personal experience its not enough you must test everything on real device.
for the error be sure use the GPS permission in the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

and change this lines

```
String msg = "Current Location: " +
Double.toString(currentLocation.getLatitude()) + "," +
Double.toString(currentLocation.getLongitude());
```

to :

```
String msg = "Current Location: " +
String.format("%9.6f",currentLocation.getLongitude()) +"," +
String.format("%9.6f", currentLocation.getLatitude()));
```

Comment: Yes i have given permission and i have tried your code. Still it is not working. I can see the same error.